# How to get relevance score for each article classified, Python NLP

Tags: python, classification, evaluate, article, relevance

Here is a code this code classify Text into 10 categories, it shows the overall accuracy of the algorithm at the end:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

df = pd.read_csv('data/wine_data.csv')

counter = Counter(df['variety'].tolist())
top_10_varieties = {i[0]: idx for idx, i in enumerate(counter.most_common(10))}
df = df[df['variety'].map(lambda x: x in top_10_varieties)]

description_list = df['description'].tolist()
varietal_list = [top_10_varieties[i] for i in df['variety'].tolist()]
varietal_list = np.array(varietal_list)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
x_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(description_list)


tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
x_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(x_train_counts)

train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x_train_tfidf,   varietal_list,test_size=0.3)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(train_x, train_y)
y_score = clf.predict(test_x)

n_right = 0
for i in range(len(y_score)):
if y_score[i] == test_y[i]:
    n_right += 1

print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % ((n_right/float(len(test_y)) * 100))) code here
```

My question, how to get a relevance score for each article in the dataset, like this:

[Relevance scores](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard14/uploads/prodigy/original/2X/d/d7676753b5419b27fcd902c732ba74cf48de2a3b.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the returned probability estimates for your test set using `predict_proba` method. Zipping it with the `_classes` should give you corresponding relevance.

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(test_x)

for i in range(len(test_x)):
    probs_classes = list(zip(clf._classes, probs[i]))
    print(f"X = {test_x[i]}, Predicted = {probs_classes}")
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no model created unlike in Keras.

Comment: @tursunWali Your model is your classifier, it was a typo. Change `model` with `clf`.

Comment: when I implement your method (after add these two lines: clf=svm.SVC(probability=True)
clf.fit(test_x, test_y)) it shows an error : "TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]"

Comment: I got probability for test_x in this way: 'train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(x_train_tfidf, varietal_list, test_size=0.3) clf=svm.SVC(probability=True) clf.fit(test_x, test_y) w.writerow(clf.predict_proba(test_x))'      I got probability, but not in the way I wish: there is no class names